# "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" and Unbounded wildcard

Tags: java

There are several threads regarding:

```
Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context
```

but the question here is a bit different. I noticed that with raw type I don't get this compilation error. On the other hand if I use the wildcard I get the error. Here the code I'm talking about:

```
Map<Class<? extends MySuperClass<?>>, List<MySuperClass<?>>> groupedSubClasses = 
    ids.stream().collect(groupingBy(MySuperClass::getClass));
```

This code won't compile because of the above error. Instead:

```
Map<Class<? extends MySuperClass>, List<MySuperClass>> groupedSubClasses = 
        ids.stream().collect(groupingBy(MySuperClass::getClass));
```

will compile.

So what is the "relation" between this error and raw type/wildcard?

Comment: Is `MySuperClass` a “top level” class? A single raw type will cause all generics to be removed so the reason it compiling may be less obvious than it seems.

Comment: Yes is an abstract top level class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it